# Entity Framework 6 still requires EF5 ProviderName "System.Data.EntityClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I updated an ASP.NET MVC5 application from EF4 to EF6 and so changed all references from `System.Data.EntityClient` to `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient`.

However, the application won't work -- it throws a 500 server error, "connection string doesn't work with this version of EF" -- unless I change the `providerName` attribute of the connection string *back* to `System.Data.EntityClient`!

I'm not even quite sure how it gets a reference to `System.Data.EntityClient` in the first place -- the app is using all EF6 DLLs.

Perhaps relevant:

- I wanted to avoid updating my `ObjectContext` to a `DbContext` so I used the available `EF 6.x EntityObject Generator` to create my entity model. But the generated classes are headed with `using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;` as they should be.
- The data provider is MySql (`provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`), using MySQL Connector 6.9.6.

Comment: I observe the same behaviour, though in my case it is a SQL Server database

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a common issue -- can't imagine why. We need a .Net internals person! Anyway, I was happy just getting it to work, even if not knowing why.

Comment: I've got a connection problem for just one of many connections when I upgraded a very large solution from EF5 to EF6:  (Outer exception: "The underlying provider failed on Open.", inner exception: "Login failed for user 'ConsentStatus'."). I was just about to try changing the providerName in my connection strings as you did. :^/